# Prove $5x-3y+z<1$ is an open set

Tags: general-topology, multivariable-calculus

> Prove: $A=\{(x,y,x)\in \mathbb{R}^{n}:5x-3y+z<1\}$ is an open set

To prove this we need to take a general $x\in A$ and find a $\delta>0$ such that all $x\in A$ will be inside an open ball that is contained in A

But how should I approach this? $z$ and $y$ can get any value, so I dont know which radius of a ball to take so they will be inside

Remark: I am doing my first steps in $R^n$ topology as an intro to multivariable calculus (real analysis)

Comment: the preimage of an open set under a continuous functions is open

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let
$f :  \mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R$

$(x,y,z) \mapsto 5x-3y+z$.

it is easy to prove that $f$ is continuous  as a sum of continuous functions.

as

$A=f^{-1}((-\infty,1))$,

and $(-\infty,1)$ is an open in $\mathbb R$, we can state that $A$ is an open in$\;\;\mathbb R^3$.

Comment: Shouldn't we say something on $f^{-1}$?

Comment: @gbox it's the preimage.

Answer (score 2):

Let $(x,y,z) \in A$, we can compute its distance to the hyperplane to be $d=\frac{|5x-3y+z-1|}{\sqrt{5^2+3^2+1^2}}>0$.

Let the radius be $\frac{d}{2}$ and the ball will be sufficient small that it doesn't touch the hyperplane.

Comment: So $\delta=\frac{d}{2}$?

Comment: yup, that should be sufficiently small.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X_0 =(x_0,y_0,z_0) \in A$. Then $1 - (5x_0-3y_0+z_0) := \epsilon > 0$. Then $B_0:=B(X_0, \frac{\epsilon}{9}) \subset A$. Indeed, let $(x,y,z) \in B_0$. Then we have

\begin{align*} 
1- (5x - 3y + z) &= 1 - (5x - 3y + z - (5x_0-3y_0+z_0) + (5x_0-3y_0+z_0))\\
&= 1 - (5(x-x_0) - 3(y-y_0) + (z-z_0) + (5x_0-3y_0+z_0))\\
&= \epsilon - (5(x-x_0) - 3(y-y_0) + (z-z_0))
\end{align*}

But one has the following bound:
\begin{align*} 
5(x-x_0) - 3(y-y_0) + (z-z_0) < 5\frac{\epsilon}{9} + 3 \frac{\epsilon}{9} + \frac{\epsilon}{9} = \epsilon
\end{align*}

Therefore, we have:

\begin{align*}
1- (5x - 3y + z) =\epsilon - (5(x-x_0) - 3(y-y_0) + (z-z_0)) > 0
\end{align*}

Hence $(x,y,z) \in A$.